# SLES 11 Root account password is not Expiring

Tags: linux, passwords

I want to expiry the root password after Max days and on next login want user to update the new password.

But even after the password is expired, it is not prompting the user to change the password and I am able to login the system using root user.

chage -l root
Minimum: 0 
Maximum: 1 
Warning: 7 
Inactive: 0 
Last Change: Mar 02, 2020 
Password Expires: Mar 03, 2020 
Password Inactive: Mar 03, 2020 
Account Expires: Never

Still I am able to login into the system.

Comment: Enforcing password changes is considered poor security practise these days.

Comment: And especially for root.